# How to see EKS Fargate FluentBit logs for debugging?

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, fluent-bit

Is there any way I can see FluentBit logs for EKS Fargate? I'd like to see the errors that are raised by the plugins.

The EKS Fargate logging manual provides a way [to see if the ConfigMap is valid](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-logging.html#fargate-logging-troubleshooting). The ConfigMap entry I'm using is valid, but there seem to be some issues in the plugin because the logs aren't created in Cloudwatch and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out AWS provides a way - we need to put the flag `flb_log_cw: "true"` under `data` in the ConfigMap ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-logging.html)), and that would output the FluentBit logs to Cloudwatch logs.